# Schema to accept array with object or string

Tags: database, elasticsearch, database-design, database-schema, elasticsearch-5

Need to store array data in Elasticsearch. The array can contain a string or object so I can accept both array types. I'm able to do this by defining individual array types. But I need a generic solution that accepts strings or objects in an array.

Object to store in Elasticsearch :

```
{
  "anotherData": [
     {
        "someData": {
            "testingName": [
                {
                    "alternateName": "Another data",
                    "areaCategory": "some data"
                }
            ]
        }
     }
   ]
}
```

Elasticsearch schema for storing above data :

```
{
  ....
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "testingName": {
        "properties": {
          "alternateName": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "areaCategory": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      ....
    }
  }
}
```

Another example of an object to store :

```
{
"anotherData": [
    {
        "someData": {
            "testingName": [
                "this is only a array string"
            ]
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

For the above object the Elasticsearch schema would be :

```
{
  ....
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "testingName": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      ....
    }
  }
}
```

I need to combine both in the schema as "any of one" condition. I can store any of the above two objects which could be an array of strings or an array of objects. Please share the Elasticsearch schema that can work for both types.

Comment: your second example and mapping are the same as the first, but you refer to it being an object. that doesn't match up though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to store either objects or string in the **same field** is by using the following mapping, i.e. a [disabled object](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html)

```
  "testingName": {
    "type": "object",
    "enabled": false
  }
```

This means that your source documents will be allowed to have a `testingName` field which contains either a string or an object but the BIG drawback is that you will **not be able to query** on that field.

In terms of data design, it makes no sense to have such "bicephalic" fields, at least ES doesn't support that. You would be better off having two different fields, one for strings and another for objects.

**UPDATE:**

Here is a full recreation of the solution:

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "testingName": {
        "type": "object",
        "enabled": false
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT test/_doc/1
{
  "testingName": [
    "test"
  ]
}

PUT test/_doc/2
{
  "testingName": [
    {
      "alternateName": "test",
      "areacategory": "test"
    }
  ]
}

GET test/_search
```

Returns

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "test",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "1",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "testingName" : [
        "test"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "test",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "2",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "testingName" : [
        {
          "alternateName" : "test",
          "areacategory" : "test"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: the closest you can get is https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/multi-fields.html

Comment: @MarkWalkom I don't think this would work since the field is supposed to contain an array of either string or objects. Multi-fields are objects by definition and wouldn't allow that